# Styling a right menu bar in html and css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style a page with a righthand side bar that has a menu. I am using div tags. What I get looks close, but it is not obvious to me how to create the menu div in the right bar that should contain the rotated menu item divs. The image illustrates what I mean. The right bar is transparent such that the main page content below is visible. I want to animate the bar div with Javascript but accomplished that already.

[image]

Currently, I have in my css

```
#menu_list {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    transform-origin: center top;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(300%) rotate(-90deg);
}
#menu_list p {
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#right_bar {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 30%;
        overflow: auto;
        padding: 0;
}
```

and as html

```
<div id="bar_wrapper" onclick="toggleMenu()">
<div>
<div id="menu_list">
    <p>Info</p>
    <p>About</p>
</div>
<div style="width:30%; height:100%; position:fixed; top:0; right:0; bottom:0;">
<h4>
    Info
</h4>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

but that, like other things that I have tried, does not quite do it.

Comment: To create a div coming off of the right bar, you probably just need `position: absolute` with `left` also specified. However, it's hard to tell, as you don't supply any code, or any examples of what you have already tried. Please see [How To Create An Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To rotate text, you'll need the `transform` property, which unfortunately has a different property across each browser. See [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/text-rotation/).

Comment: Some of the trouble I am having seems to be related to the rotation of the text. Should that be too awkward, a valid alternative could be to include the menu items as svg images.

Answer (score 0):

use css transform property on your default navbar.

```
#div_name {
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
transform: rotate(-90deg);
```

}

but I think it won't look responsive.but will look exactly as like u want

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBWem.png)

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean. Which is `div_name`?

Comment: I have added an Image  .hope it will help you div_name means the navbar  div name  sorry for not being cleared.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
jsfiddle.net/TiG3R/bLksqtpw
```

for rotating navbar you should rotate navbar div not rotate tabs, look at example

Comment: Thanks. My problems arise when I nest the rotated menu in the right bar div. Somehow, I can't get the placement right under these conditions.

Comment: If I paste your code, replacing the quoted `menu_list` div, the navbar is not visible (outside of screen).

Comment: you should change your class , if you need that id add it again , try this: http://jsfiddle.net/TiG3R/bLksqtpw/1/ | its work for me , i just give you the main code and learn you how to rotate your navbar , i can create your site! | Please accept the answer if it works for you

Comment: I pasted your code. The problem is likely that it does not work with the style of the bar_wrapper div, which I need to place the whole thing on the right edge of the screen.